# Driver_Power_State_Failure BSOD

Tags: drivers, bsod, crash

I was using my computer normally when it crashed with the BSOD message "DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE". This happened shortly after resuming from sleep. It is a new laptop with 4 external monitors connected, but my old laptop could handle this situation fine, so it is not necessarily related.

I have a new USB 3 hub that could be doing something weird, but other than that, nothing is abnormal. Event Viewer shows nothing out of the ordinary before the crash.

Here is the minidump file. There is another one at C:/Windows/MEMORY.DMP but it is 1.6 GB in size.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o1JwMQEDaDI8QQ1KJQdLBBiGKxqOorQo/view?usp=sharing

If somebody could analyze the file and figure out what is causing the crash, that would be great!
Thank you in advance

Comment: the analysis provided by this website seems to show that it <i>was</i> caused by the usb hub (or A usb hub). Any way to verify this or find out which hub? http://www.osronline.com

Comment: no, look at my answer. the Logitech Webcam drivers cause the crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Analyzing the dump with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) shows that the drivers `LVUSBS64.sys` and `lvuvc64.sys`

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE (9f)
A driver has failed to complete a power IRP within a specific time.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000003, A device object has been blocking an Irp for too long a time
Arg2: ffffb702cb03c8d0, Physical Device Object of the stack
Arg3: fffff800adda57f0, nt!TRIAGE_9F_POWER on Win7 and higher, otherwise the Functional Device Object of the stack
Arg4: ffffb702cbe02870, The blocked IRP

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1


TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.16299.192 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  GS63 7RD

SYSTEM_SKU:  16K4.1

SYSTEM_VERSION:  REV:1.0

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  E16K4IMS.10C

BIOS_DATE:  06/22/2017

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  MS-16K4

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  REV:1.0

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: 3

BUGCHECK_P2: ffffb702cb03c8d0

BUGCHECK_P3: fffff800adda57f0

BUGCHECK_P4: ffffb702cbe02870

DRVPOWERSTATE_SUBCODE:  3

IMAGE_NAME:  usbccgp.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

MODULE_NAME: usbccgp

FAULTING_MODULE: fffff80def920000 usbccgp

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: af8

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 9e

CPU_STEPPING: 9

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,9e,9,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 5E'00000000 (cache) 5E'00000000 (init)

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXPNP: 1 (!blackboxpnp)


CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x9F

PROCESS_NAME:  System

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.17046.1000 amd64fre

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff800`adda57b8 fffff800`ab0d3957 : 00000000`0000009f 00000000`00000003 ffffb702`cb03c8d0 fffff800`adda57f0 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff800`adda57c0 fffff800`ab0d3862 : ffffb702`cbb4d5d0 fffff800`a9226180 00000000`00000020 00000000`00000080 : nt!PopIrpWatchdogBugcheck+0xeb
fffff800`adda5820 fffff800`aaf4a533 : ffffb702`cbb4d608 fffff800`a9226180 fffff800`adda5a18 00000000`00000000 : nt!PopIrpWatchdog+0x22
fffff800`adda5870 fffff800`aaf4b5cd : 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000000 00000000`0029d7a9 fffff800`a9226180 : nt!KiProcessExpiredTimerList+0x153
fffff800`adda5960 fffff800`ab015fca : 00000000`00000000 fffff800`a9226180 00000000`001a6f79 fffff800`ab2b5380 : nt!KiRetireDpcList+0x43d
fffff800`adda5b60 00000000`00000000 : fffff800`adda6000 fffff800`add9f000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x5a


IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.16299.64

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_lvuvc64_IMAGE_usbccgp.sys

BUCKET_ID:  0x9F_3_lvuvc64_IMAGE_usbccgp.sys

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0x9F_3_lvuvc64_IMAGE_usbccgp.sys

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0x9f_3_lvuvc64_image_usbccgp.sys

---------

0: kd> !irp ffffb702cbe02870;!podev ffffb702cb03c8d0
Irp is active with 24 stacks 22 is current (= 0xffffb702cbe02f28)
 No Mdl: No System Buffer: Thread 00000000:  Irp stack trace.  Pending has been returned
     cmd  flg cl Device   File     Completion-Context
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-00000000    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
 [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_WAIT_WAKE(0)]
            0  0 ffffb702cb03c8d0 00000000 fffff80ded344e30-ffffb702bfe437f0    
           \Driver\usbccgp  ks!CKsDevice::CompleteDevicePowerIrp
            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000002
>[IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0  1 ffffb702cd2f3680 00000000 00000000-00000000    pending
          Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\lvuvc64.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for lvuvc64.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for lvuvc64.sys
 \Driver\LVUVC64
            Args: 00041100 00000001 00000001 00000002
 [IRP_MJ_POWER(16), IRP_MN_SET_POWER(2)]
            0 e1 ffffb702cba79060 00000000 fffff800aafbb5a0-ffffb702cbb4d5d0 Success Error Cancel pending
           \Driver\ksthunk  nt!PopRequestCompletion
            Args: 00041100 00000001 00000001 00000002
 [N/A(0), N/A(0)]
            0  0 00000000 00000000 00000000-ffffb702cbb4d5d0    

            Args: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
Device object is for:
  DriverObject c635a5e0
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 0 Type 00000022 AttachedDev ffffb702cbe7a3d0 DevFlags 00003040  DO_POWER_PAGABLE
Device queue is not busy.
Device Object Extension: ffffb702cb03cf90:
PowerFlags: 00000010 =>SystemState=0 DeviceState=1
Dope: 00000000:
0: kd> !devstack ffffb702cbe7a3d0
  !DevObj           !DrvObj            !DevExt           ObjectName
  ffffb702cba79060  \Driver\ksthunk    ffffb702cba791b0  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffb702cba79030

  ffffb702cd2f3680  \Driver\LVUVC64    ffffb702cd2f37f0  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffb702cd2f3650

> ffffb702cbe7a3d0 Unable to load image \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\LVUSBS64.sys, Win32 error 0n2
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for LVUSBS64.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for LVUSBS64.sys
 \Driver\LVUSBS64   ffffb702cbe7a520  InfoMask field not found for _OBJECT_HEADER at ffffb702cbe7a3a0

  ffffb702cb03c8d0  \Driver\usbccgp    ffffb702cb03ca20  Cannot read info offset from nt!ObpInfoMaskToOffset

!DevNode ffffb702cad69910 :
  DeviceInst is "USB\VID_046D&PID_08C1&MI_00\7&1d1d15db&0&0000"
  ServiceName is "LVUVC64"
0: kd> lmvm lvuvc64
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff800`c42b0000 fffff800`c4620500   lvuvc64  T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: lvuvc64.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\lvuvc64.sys
    Image name: lvuvc64.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Sat May 12 01:59:12 2007 (46450350)
    CheckSum:         0037D627
    ImageSize:        00370500
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
    Information from resource tables:
0: kd> lmvm LVUSBS64
Browse full module list
start             end                 module name
fffff80d`ed3c0000 fffff80d`ed3ca900   LVUSBS64 T (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: LVUSBS64.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\drivers\LVUSBS64.sys
    Image name: LVUSBS64.sys
    Browse all global symbols  functions  data
    Timestamp:        Sat May 12 02:01:20 2007 (464503D0)
    CheckSum:         000157CE
    ImageSize:        0000A900
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
    Information from resource tables:
```

Those are `Logitech Webcam drivers`, so update those really old drivers.

Comment: Thank you! (it's a really old webcam, so probably no new drivers). That also explains why windows occasionally throws up error messages related to it.